# Run "logout script" for non-login shells

Tags: bash, logout

I have a `.bash_logout` script that I've put in the home directories of the *vagrant* and *root* users of a VM (created, as you have already guessed, with [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com)) that I'm using for development.

The script copies all my important dot files into a directory that is shared between the host OS and the guest OS, so that I can easily check them into my Git repo, track changes, and more easily carry over improvements I've made in the configuration of one VM to another.

The problem I'm running into (which you have also probably guessed) is that the the script never runs for the *root* user, since I `su` to *root* rather than log in as *root*.

Is there anyway to make a script run every time you `exit` a shell you entered by `su`ing to another user?  Not technically a logout script, I suppose, but pretty nearly the same thing in spirit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a login shell with `su` like so:

```
su - [user]
```

If you do not wish to create a login shell, you can use an exit trap.

```
trap_exit() {
    . "$HOME/.bash_logout"
}
trap trap_exit EXIT
```

Put the above code in the users' `.bashrc` files.

Comment: D'oh! Of course, the `-`.  I ended up putting `trap . "$HOME/.bash_logout" 0` in the `.bashrc` before coming back here and being reminded why I should always use `-`... a forgotten habit...